# What is the strategy to beat Dragonite?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a pokemon that one can level up (or some other strategy) that would counter [Dragonite](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Dragonite_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) well?

Comment: Whenever you need to beat Dragonite, just remember what this famous rapper said, "Ice Ice Baby".

Comment: There's... strategy?  You press the screen until it dies!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Dragonite is nothing special. Ok, it has high stats and a few resistances but the same tactics work on it. Dodge its attacks and try to get type advantages.

If you haven't read it already, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275754/is-dodging-an-effective-strategy-and-if-so-how-can-i-use-it-most-optimally) has answers about how to dodge optimally. It applies to all pokemon, but is especially important against higher CP opponents, which Dragonites usually are.

Dragonite is a Dragon/Flying pokemon. This gives it a double weakness to Ice, making Ice moves extremely effective. It is also weak against Dragon, Rock, and Fairy moves. A pokemon with one or both moves of this type can deal a lot of damage.

Bear in mind, however, that Dragonite's resistances include Water, Fighting, and Ground, which Ice and Rock pokemon often use. It's also resistant to Fire, Bug, and Grass. Make sure neither of your attacks are these types.

Dragonite has a few attacks- fighting the Dragonite once to discover them will make fighting it a second time much easier. Its basic moves are Dragon Breath and Steel Wing, with Dragon Breath being significantly more popular due to its STAB bonus.

Steel and Fairy pokemon are resistant to Dragon moves. Dragons are weak against them but unless you are using your own Dragonite, that's not an issue.

Steel Wing Dragonites are less popular but are extremely dangerous. Steel is super effective against Fairy, Ice, and Rock pokemon- all of Dragonite's weaknesses. Steel is, fortunately, ineffective against Water so a Water/Ice or a Water pokemon with Ice moves can do well here.

Dragonite has 3 possible special attacks. Dragon Claw and Dragon Pulse are dragon- see above. Hyper Beam is normal type. It's also Hyper Beam. Don't worry about type advantages here- if it hits you, you'll probably die.

And so, the best options I've found:

1. A bigger Dragonite. Obviously.
2. Non-dragons with Dragon attacks. I have two Gyaradoses for this- they know Dragon Breath and Dragon Pulse and between them have destroyed CP 3000 Dragonites.
3. Water/Ice types with double Ice moves. Lapras is the strongest option here but Cloyster or Dewgong also work. They do need to both be ice moves (in Lapras' case, ice and dragon) because of Dragonite's resistance to Water.
4. Magneton. Neutral effectiveness, resistant to everything Dragonite can use.
5. Fairy types. Clefable and Wigglytuff are bad against Steel Wing, but resistant to Dragon and can have at least one super-effective STAB Fairy move.
6. Slowbro is also good because it has lots of health and can have Ice Beam which does 65 damage now

Answer (score 2):

The strategy behind defeating Pokemons lies in the **"Type"** of Pokemons; by using a Pokemon with a super effective move. Dragonite is a dragon type Pokemon, which is weak against Dragon-type & Fairy-type moves (Fairy types come in later generation of Pokemon series).

So, 1 strategy is to use a Pokemon with Fairy-type moves against Dragonite to defeat it.

There are many Pokemons in Pokemon GO that may know Fairy type moves (refer to the wiki linked above) and you can use those moves to effectively defeat Dragonite easily.

An alternative solution is to look at the other type of Dragonite and which is - **Flying**.

Flying type Pokemons are weak against - Ice, Rock and Electric.

But here, Electric won't work well as Dragonite has high Electric moves resistivity.

So, the key to defeating Dragonite is to use a Pokemon with Rock or Ice type moves in Pokemon GO.

Here are the possible Rock and Ice type Pokemons you can use against Dragonite (if they have ice or rock type move):

1. **Dewgong** - An Ice type Pokemon which is sure to have either a Basic or a Special take of Ice type. I've again and again used Dewgong's Ice type super-effective moves to defeat Dragonite.
2. **Slowbro** - Again, Slowbro would sometimes have Ice type move like Ice beam which is a super effective move.
3. **Golem** - A Pokemon with rock type moves
4. **Aerodactyl** - Aerodactyl is Rock and Flying type Pokemon which may have those super-effective rock moves against Dragonite.

There are many other Pokemons like Diglett, Shellder, Kabutops, Lapras, etc which may have Ice or Rock type move which can be used to defeat Dragonite faster as these moves are super-effective to it.

Comment: If Dragonite itself knows electric type moves ((which it doesn't in Pokemon Go)) That would make an electric pokemon **more** effective against it, not less, since it would be super effective vs Dragonite and resist one of its' moves. Additionally, Fairy type moves are super effective vs Dragon types and Fairy types resist Dragon Type moves,  making Fairy pokemon good for taking down Dragon Types.

Comment: @RFKomos Yes, Dragonite do knows Electric type moves in the actual GBA games. Don't know why it doesn't in Pokemon GO. And NO, Dragonite's that wouldn't make electric type moves super effective against dragonite (does any electric type Pokemons feel Opposite Electric moves as super effective? Electric is dragonite's 3rd type)

Fairy types were the one I didn't consider since they were introduced in the later generation but are still included in Pokemon GO. I've edited the answer to include it. Thanks for reminding that.

Comment: Please add any relevant information to your answer instead of relying on a link—links can and do "break" when sites go down or are reorganised, which will make the link useless. Since the mission of Arqade is to store useful answers forever, summarising the relevant information from the link will both improve your answer and protect it from future breakage.

Comment: The answer is already explained in depth.

Comment: Aerodactyl only has one rock-type move and it is literally one of the worst. You are better off using almost anything else, even after weaknesses are considered.

Answer (score 2):

I have had great luck with Clefable. Fairy type, for whatever reason, is super effective against Dragon types. Clefables are beefcakes, and they can put out a surprising amount of damage. Alternatively a decently powerful Jolteon will do just fine.

Remember, you only get a 20% bonus either way for typing. Focus on building a diverse, high CP team and you'll do fine.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with using Clefable against dragonite is that Clefable's normal moves are not fairy at all! They are "Pound" (normal) and "Zen Headbutt" (psychic).  Neither is specially effective against dragons. The best Clefable charge move against dragons is "Moonblast", but you don't use it often enough to defeat Dragonite.  Dragons with Steel Wing are super effective against Clefable.  Wigglytuff fares just as poorly with similar move disadvantages.  You have to forget about the so-called fairy advantage in Pokemon Go.

What I have succeeded with repeatedly is big Water pokemon: Vaporeon and Gyarados.  Sunday I trained at a friendly Gymn with great prestige and with the lower three Pokémon being 2250 Arcanine, 2250 Charizard, and 2400 Dragoniite.  One Vaporeon defeated Arcanine and Charizard then weakened Draginite enough so that the second Vaporeon defeated not just Dragonite but also the Snorlax above.  Vaporeon followed by Gyarados was equally effective, but Vaporeon followed by Clefable was never able to defeat the bottom three.  The Vaporeon have Water Gun/Hydropump, the Gyarados has Bite/Dragon Pulse, and Clefable Pound and Moonblast.  My best guess is that the Dragonite had Steel Wing/Dragon Pulse.

Answer (score 1):

I use my 1400 dewgong to defeat many 2300+ dragonites. The frost breath is super effective against the dragonite and it can shoot a frost breath each second which makes it more lethal.

Answer (score 1):

I find that my 1700 CP Steelix can take down a 3200 CP Dragonite as long as I dodge Hyper Beam! Steelix is a Steel-type so Hyper Beam is less effective against me. My primary move is Dragon Tail, which is super-effective against Dragon-types and I have a Steel-type charge attack. I bring out Steelix for every Dragon-type. That said, Cloyster and Dewgong with Ice-type moves also work.